# How to Register .NET dll as COM using Wix?

Tags: winforms

I am using the following code for registering .net dll as COM but after installing the application it is not showing any entries in the Registry Editor.

Code:

```
<Component Id="Symcon.LightRidge.RunControlSetProxy" Guid="*">
      <File Id="Symcon.LightRidge.RunControlSetProxy" KeyPath="yes" Source="D:\PE-Advisor Source code 4-26 11-July-2012 (Dowloaded from FTP site on19-Oct-12)\08 DesktopApplication\ExternalLib\Symcon.LightRidge.RunControlSetProxy.dll" SelfRegCost="1"/>
       </Component>
```

Comment: Read this tutorial: http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea

Comment: I went through the tutorial and i made some changes in the code but still it is not showing any entries in the Registry Editor.So kindly suggest how to proceed further.